# How to combine htaccess 301 rules properly

Tags: .htaccess

To my knowledge, htaccess files are parsed from "top down".

So I tried this:

Define some explicit URL redirects.

```
Redirect 301 /de/category/product.html http://shop.de/category/productnewurl
...
...
```

And additionally remove all /de/ from all other URLs not explicitly caught above with the below "catch all" statement.

```
RewriteRule ^de((?:(?:\s*|/.*)$)) $1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

For some reason this is not working. I tried to move the above catch all directive before and after the explicit URL redirects. Both without success.

Additionally, while the "catch all" directive is active, none of the explicit url redirect work any longer. What am I overseeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect` is from `mod_alias` module and `RewriteRule` is from `mod_rewrite` module. It is not a good idea to mix both directives together as these modules are invoked at different times by Apache engine.

Better stick to `mod_rewrite` rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^de/category/product\.html$ http://shop.de/category/productnewurl [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^de((?:(?:\s*|/.*)$)) $1 [L,NC,R=301]
```